# Problem with v-autocomplete with chips - Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js, chips

I have been trying to use the v-autocomplete with chips and unfortunately, I'm having a problem rendering the chips. When we use the search-input property with .sync, to be able to do a search directly in the API, when selecting the item in the listing, the selected chip simply does not appear.

A workaround for this I found is to use the cached-items property, but it always caches the items retrieved from the API.

Has anyone had a problem similar to this one?

https://codepen.io/leonardoabreu/pen/ExbovOZ

Vuetify version: 2.5.6

Code:

```
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    v-model="myModel"
    :items="searchResults"
    :search-input.sync="searchTerms"
    return-object
    class="user-search"
    append-icon="mdi-magnify"
    background-color="white"
    item-text="email"
    item-value="email"
    chips
    deletable-chips
    filled
    hide-no-data
    hide-selected
    outlined
    persistent-placeholder
    @keydown.esc="onEscPressed"
    @keydown.enter="onInputChanged"
    @input.native="onInputChanged"
    @change="resetSearchTerms"
    v-on="$listeners"
  >
    <template #selection="{ item, attrs, selected, select }">
      <v-chip
        v-bind="attrs"
        :input-value="selected"
        close
        @click="select"
        @click:close="$emit('onRemoveResult', item.email)"
      >
        {{ item.email }}
      </v-chip>
    </template>

    <template #item="{ item }">
      <v-list-item-content v-text="item.email" />
    </template>
  </v-autocomplete>
</template>

export default {
  name: 'MySearch',
  data: () => ({
    myModel: [],
    loading: false,
    searchResults: [],
    searchTerms: '',
  }),
  computed: {
    filters() {
      return { name: this.searchTerms?.trim() || '' };
    },
  },
  methods: {
    searchUsers() {
      if (this.searchTerms?.length < 3) {
        this.searchResults = [];
        return;
      }

      this.loading = true;

      this.searchResults = [
        { name: "First Name", email: "first@foo.com" },
        { name: "Second Name", email: "second@foo.com" },
      ]

      this.loading = false;
    },
    onInputChanged() {
      if (!this.searchTerms || this.searchTerms?.length < 3) {
        this.searchResults = [];
        return;
      }

      this.searchUsers();
    },
    onEscPressed() {
      this.resetSearchTerms();
    },
    resetSearchTerms() {
      this.searchTerms = '';
      this.searchResults = [];
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, your problem is that the *cached items* are listed after you select one of the items in the list, but you want them to not show, right?

Assuming that's the case, a workaround you can use here is to replace the `v-autocomplete` `cachedItems` data value for its `lazyValue` on the change event.

To do that, you'll need to add a `ref` prop to you `v-autocomplete`:

```html
  <v-autocomplete
    ref="search-autocomplete"
    ...
```

Then, in your `change` event method, replace the `cachedItems` for the `lazyValue` (`value` doesn't work here because by the time the change event triggers, `value` still hasn't been computed):

```js
this.$refs['search-autocomplete'].cachedItems = this.$refs['search-autocomplete'].lazyValue;
```

Comment: No problem! Good to know